# Conection problem trying to connect Linux with SQL Server on Windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, php

I've 2 servers connected to the same network. One of this, is a Fedora web server which contains the webpage and a form. The other one, is a Windows Server 2008 R2 which contains a SQL Server 2012.

I install sqlsrv extension into the webserver, to connect the form to my databse on the Windows Server.

I've followed the Microsoft tutorials, but still doesn't work at all. When I try to enter onto the form, several errors ocurred.

In phpinfo appears the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv. So I tried with different codes in different files, but all of them give a different error.

**testpdo.php**

```
<?php
    $serverName = "192.168.9.10:1433";
    $database = "logytel";
    $uid = 'sa';
    $pwd = 'pass';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO(
            "odbc:mssql=$serverName;Database=$database",
            $uid,
            $pwd,
            array(
                //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo "<p>Connected to SQL Server</p>\n";
    echo "<p>PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT value:</p>\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_export($conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT), true);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<p>PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME value:</p>\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_export($conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME), true);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<p>PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION value:</p>\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_export($conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), true);
    echo "</pre>";
    $query = 'select top 5 * from tbl_users';
    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
    echo "<pre>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print_r($row);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    // Free statement and connection resources.
    $stmt = null;
    $conn = null;
?>
```

And this error occur when trying to connect to it

> Error connecting to SQL Server: could not find driver

**testsql.php**

```
<?php
    function FormatErrors( $errors )
    {

     /* Display errors. */

     echo "Error information: <br/>";


      if(!$errors || is_array($errors) ) {
           return ;
      }

     foreach ( $errors as $error );

     {

     echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";

     echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";

     echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";

     }

    }

$q = isset($_GET['q'])? intval($_GET['q']) : 0;
$serverName = "192.168.9.10:1433";
$conInfo = array ( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    sqlsrv_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM prueba1 WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";

    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);

    if ($getResults == FALSE) {

      die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }


    $cantidad_encontrado = sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults);

    if ($cantidad_encontrado > 0) {
            // solo se pone los ; (punto y comas) al finalizar la sentencias, no entre lineas de tu echo.
            echo "<table>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Código</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellidos</th>
                  <th>Proyecto</th>
                  </tr>";  //<- aqui termina la sentencia, lo que esta arriba es solo texto plano que el compilador interpreta como STRING y no como sentencia

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults)) {
                echo "<tr>";                                 // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
                echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";


    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
    sqlsrv_close($con);


    }else{
        echo "<h1>NO ENCONTRE DATOS </h1>";
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">Luis</option>
          <option value="2">Nora</option>
          <option value="3">Aron</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this error occured

> La conexión no se pudo establecer. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => HYT00
>   [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [1]
>   => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
>   SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [2] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

**conect.php**

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.9.10\mssqlserver, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); var_dump($conn);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

> could not find driver

**conect1**

```
<?php
$SqlServer = "192.168.9.10:1433\MSSQLSERVER";

$SqlServerCon = new PDO("odbc:mssql=$SqlServer;Database=logytel", "sa", "pass");

if (!$SqlServerCon) {die('Unable To Connect to Sql Server');}

else
{echo "Connection Successful";} 
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   /var/www/html/conexion1.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/conexion1.php(4): PDO->__construct('odbc:mssql=192....',
>   'sa', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/conexion1.php on line
>   4

**conect2.php**

```
<?php
$SqlServer = "192.168.9.10:1433\MSSQLSERVER";

$DbConnInfo = array( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");

$SqlServerCon = sqlsrv_connect( $SqlServer, $DbConnInfo);

if( $SqlServerCon ) {echo "Connection established";}

else

{echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";

die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
?>
```

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [1]
>   => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
>   SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [2] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

And the last one, which seems to connect, but it doesn't show anything.
**try.php**

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.9.10\mssqlserver, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); var_dump($conn);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

> resource(1) of type (SQL Server Connection) Conexión establecida.

When I access with `telnet 192.168.9.10` appears *Connection refused*, but in the SQL Server the ports are open, there are firewall exceptions, I used the user **SA** for remote conections.

I don't know what to do, and I need to connect both servers. I uninstall everything and install everything again, like 3 times, without resolving the problem. I search for other ways to do it, I've tried FreeTDS, but don't know really how to use it, also . It didn't give me any errors in the installation except the one I mentioned before.

Is there any file I didn't create or edit? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are valid connection strings for SSMS login box?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134499/what-are-valid-connection-strings-for-ssms-login-box)

Comment: While my original Q&A is for Windows to SQL Server connections it has some validity for Linux to SQL Server connections. I am suggesting the answer because of the error message *Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.*.

Comment: Use a comma, not a colon, for the port.

Comment: Try omitting the instance name and port: `$serverName = "192.168.9.10"`. The instance name is needed only when connecting to a named instance listening on a port other than 1433 and port 1433 is used by default.

Comment: @Lucia Your last attempt (`try.php` script) is correct and the message `resource(1) of type (SQL Server Connection) Conexión establecida.` shows, that you have a connection. If you want to execute a statement, use `sqlsrv_query()`.